# How to specify a timeout when using Firebase Test Lab through Android Studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-test-lab

I started using the Firebase Test Lab web page to run instrumented tests of my new apps.  One of the advanced settings is "Test Timeout", which is the point Firebase will kill a long running test.

I started to launch tests directly from Android Studio (3.1.1).  In setting up tests with the run configuration editor, I can't seem to find the setting for Test Timeout.  Am I missing something or is this feature not available when launching tests from AS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to set a Test Lab timeout using the Android Studio UI.  Please feel free to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for missing functionality like this.